# How to search multiple cells when the searched value is mixed within other values in the same cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, substring, worksheet-function

I am looking for a keyword that might be inside a range of cells mixed with other words, and then return a true or false value on a different cell.

Example looking for the keyword "red" which is mixed inside other words in different cells:

[image]

Comment: You can do this with the `COUNTIF` function, see [this reference](https://exceljet.net/formula/range-contains-specific-text).

Comment: Will the colour always be the second word?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad  in this example the color to look for would be "red".  The results would be on Column D as true or false if "red" is found in any cells of the row.

Comment: @PeterT  Thanks! it worked.  =COUNTIF(A2:C2,"*"&"red"&"*")>0

Answer (score 0):

In your current table this should work, put in `D2`:

```
=LEN(SUBSTITUTE(LOWER(" "&A2&" "&B2&" "&C2&" "),LOWER(" "&D$1&" "),""))<LEN(LOWER(CONCAT(A2:C2)))+2
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
=IFERROR(FIND("red";LOWER(A2))>0;IFERROR(FIND("red";LOWER(B2))>0;IFERROR(FIND("red";LOWER(C2))>0;FALSE)))
```